# Using images in place of radio buttons

Tags: asp.net, image, radiobuttonlist, listitem

I am very new to ASP and have the following code:

```
<tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom:5px;">Would you return to this practice again?&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator SetFocusOnError="true" ID="rfvReturn" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rblReturn" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" Display="Dynamic" /></td>
    <td style="padding-bottom:5px;">
    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblReturn"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
        <asp:ListItem Value="true" Text="Yes" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="false" Text="No" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td style="padding-bottom:5px;">Would you refer a friend to this practice?&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator SetFocusOnError="true" ID="rfvRefer" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rblRefer" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" Display="Dynamic" /></td>
    <td style="padding-bottom:5px;">
    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblRefer"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
        <asp:ListItem Value="true" Text="Yes" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="false" Text="No" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This code creates the following:

[image: Current]

What I would like to do is replace the radiobuttons with images that toggle and would look like this:

[image: Preferred]

I have searched everywhere but can't seem to find a way to do it.

Comment: thank you mr2ert for the edit

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the right way to do it, but how about having the pictures as links to a javascript function.  That function could fill in a text box with either a 0 or 1 based on which one was clicked.

```
    function radiobutton() {
      document.getElementById("radiotext").value="1"; 
}
```

and then just hide the text box:

```
<div style="width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;">
<input type="text">
</div>
```

This should work...

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an ASP form, not and HTML <input>